# How to correctly draw this picture in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is the picture I want to make:
[image: ideal result]

This is generated by the following extremely ugly code:

```tex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}

\definecolor{col1}{RGB}{127,127,127}
\definecolor{col2}{RGB}{240,240,240}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut]
    \clip (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \path[yshift=10,
    postaction={
        decorate,
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark=between positions 0 and \pgfdecoratedpathlength step .01cm with {
                \pgfmathsetmacro\myval{multiply(divide(
                    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/distance from start}, \pgfdecoratedpathlength),100)};
                \pgfsetfillcolor{col2!\myval!col1};
                \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{1.5};
                \pgfusepath{fill};}
    }}] 
    (.075,.2)..([closed].2,.4)..(.8,0)..(.925,.2)..(.8,.4)..(.2,0);
    \fill[col1] (.075,.55) circle (0.052cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This code cannot be compiled because there would be many errors like this one:

```
Dimension too large. (...2,.4)..(.8,0)..(.925,.2)..(.8,.4)..(.2,0); ...)
```

However I'm able to get the result pdf and hence the picture above.

My question is this: how to draw this picture correctly? Thanks in advance for any coming suggestions ~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `pgfplots` you can use `point meta` to change the color along a graph.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[hide axis,width=8cm,height=4cm,clip=false] 
\addplot[domain=0:360,samples=720,line cap=round,        
colormap={}{ 
            color(0cm)=(gray!10);
            color(16cm)=(gray);
        },
        line width=5mm, variable=t,point meta=t,mesh]
        ({-cos(t)},{-sin(2*t)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to have the proper bounding box, you can store the line width in a macro.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[hide axis,width=8cm,height=4cm,clip=false]
\def\mylw{5mm} %<- line width 
\addplot[domain=0:360,samples=720,line cap=round,        
colormap={}{ 
            color(0cm)=(gray!10);
            color(16cm)=(gray);
        },
        line width=\mylw, variable=t,point meta=t,mesh]
        ({-cos(t)},{-sin(2*t)});
% add points to have an appropriat bounding box     
\path ([xshift=-\mylw/2,yshift=-\mylw/2]-1,-1)
 ([xshift=\mylw/2,yshift=\mylw/2]1,1);      
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm new to `pgfplots` and when I try to change the width and height of this plot sometimes there seems to be a invisible bolder and part of the picture is being cut. Do you have any idea how could I fix this?

Comment: @Jinwen Yes, there is a problem with bounding boxes in Ti*k*Z and thus `pgfplots`. The bounding box does not take into account the line width of the path. I added a second code that fixes this. Please notice that there is a deeper problem that the bounding box gets usually overestimated (but here because of the large number of samples this effect is practically invisible).