# Draw an infinity loop with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm looking to draw this design with Ti*k*Z.I learnt a lot with you guys but for this one, I have no idea about how to draw the infinite loop like this.

[image]

Comment: If you've learned a lot, I would think you can do most of this diagram.  Can you show us what you have so far?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569033/how-to-correctly-draw-this-picture-in-tikz or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569013/path-with-opacity-gradient-in-tikz/569116 could give you some starting point

Comment: Please help us help you and provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that contains some code to start with and shows which problem exactly you are struggling with.

Answer (score 6):

While solutions exist to plot such an infinity symbol ([[1]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/688042), [[2]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/663247)) we can just fake it with some arcs and curves.

The middle part that goes from top left to bottom right gets drawn separately but above the rest (that's why it's an edge) but also needs to be drawn before the nodes are constructed (that's why it's not a separate path).

The `line cap=butt` makes sure we don't see any slithers of white shining through at the connecting points (0, 2) and (6, -2) which some viewers don't render perfectly.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  radius=2, start angle=-90, line cap=round,
  arr node/.style={sloped, allow upside down, single arrow,
    single arrow head extend=+.15cm, thick, minimum height=+.7cm, fill=white},
  arr/.style ={  edge node={node[arr node, pos={#1}]{}}},
  arr'/.style={insert path={node[arr node, pos={#1}]{}}},
]
\sffamily\bfseries
\draw[line width=+1cm, sloped, text=white]
  (0, 2) edge[preaction={line cap=butt, line width=+2cm, draw=white, overlay},
              out=0, in=180, arr=.2, arr=.8] (6, -2)
  (6, -2) arc[delta angle= 180]
    [arr'=.5] node[very near start]{Study} node[very near end]{Measure}
  to[out=180, in=0, arr=.2, arr=.8] (0, -2) arc[delta angle=-180]
    [arr'=.5] node[very near start]{Build} node[very near end]{Maintain};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: whaou, amazing work, thank you so much. The arr parameter is the thing I should learn with that arc figure. Thanks, I improve a lot with you.